# Magento2 Braintree Timing

Tags: magento-2.1, braintree

How long do you have between an order being placed to fulfill the order and capture the funds?  I understand that the auth will expire, if that happens with the extension just attempt a new authcapture?

Comment: accept the answer If you find It helpful

Answer (score 1):

The amount of time a transaction spends in the Settling state mostly depends on the processing bank.

Order amount `Authorization` will expired in certain cases,

- American Express authorizations will be marked as expired after 7 days.
- Mastercard authorizations created by a subscription or using the recurring flag will be marked as expired after 7 days.
- Visa authorizations will be marked as expired after 10 days.
- All other authorizations will be marked as expired after 30 days.

For more info, you can visit [Braintree site](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/statuses#authorization-expired) or contact [sales team](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact)